# Problems with frame size cv2.videocapture

Tags: python, numpy, opencv

I am new in programming and I wanted to make my first object detection. I wanted to take a picture of the background and compare it every time with the actual frame in my videopcapture. To avoid small movements I filtered the biggest contour and area. This is my code

```
b_frame = cv2.imread('background.png') 
b_frame_gray = cv2.cvtColor(b_frame,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0) 

len_contours = []
y_val = []
x_val = []

x = 0

cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT,720)
cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH,1080)
while True: 

    ret, frame = cap.read(0) 

    frame_gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    Diff = cv2.absdiff(b_frame_gray,frame_gray)
    thresh1 = cv2.threshold(Diff, 50,200, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)[1]
    image, contours,hierarchy = cv2.findContours(thresh1, cv2.RETR_CCOMP, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

    for i in range(0,len(contours)):
        len_contours.append((i,len(contours)))

    Con_max = np.where(len_contours == np.amax(len_contours))

    Contour_area = cv2.Contour_area(contours[Con_max[0]])

    if Contour_area >= 1000:


        for i in range(0,len(contours[Con_max[0]])):
            x_werte.append(contours[14][i,0,0])
            y_werte.append(contours[14][i,0,1])

        xmin = np.amin(x_val)
        xmax = np.amax(x_val)
        ymin = np.amin(y_val)
        ymax = np.amax(y_val)
        cv2.rectangle(frame,(xmin,ymax),(xmax,ymin),(255,255,255),10)

    else:
        pass



    cv2.imshow('Video Movement Detection', frame) 

    c = cv2.waitKey(1) 
    if c == 27: 
        break 

cap.release() 
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

this is my error

```
     15     frame_gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
---> 16     Diff = cv2.absdiff(b_frame_gray,frame_gray)
     17     thresh1 = cv2.threshold(Diff, 50,200, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)[1]
     18     image, contours,hierarchy = cv2.findContours(thresh1, cv2.RETR_CCOMP, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

error: OpenCV(3.4.2) /opt/concourse/worker/volumes/live/9523d527-1b9e-48e0-7ed0-a36adde286f0/volume/opencv-suite_1535558719691/work/modules/core/src/arithm.cpp:659: error: (-209:Sizes of input arguments do not match) The operation is neither 'array op array' (where arrays have the same size and the same number of channels), nor 'array op scalar', nor 'scalar op array' in function 'arithm_op'
```

it seems that the given frames in Diff do not fit therefore I adjusted with cap.set(... the width and height of the frame but it still does not work

thank you :)

Comment: Not all cameras set width and height exactly as you request - some pad to multiples of 16 for example. Try checking the sizes of the 2 frames you are comparing by printing `frame_gray.shape`

Comment: thank you for your response ! Meanwhile I fixed it by taking a picture with cv2. video capture. Furthermore I had a couple of errors in my code but now it is working !